# Boolean expression in a select list

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to return a boolean expression in a select list in Oracle? For example, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
with tbl (id, number_as_str) as (
  select 1, '3'  from dual
  union all select 2,'2' from dual
)
select id, number_as_str, id=number_as_str from tbl;
```

How would I do the equivalent of `expr = expr` in a select_list?

Comment: No can do. Oracle does not have a formal boolean type, but only boolean predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle SQL does not have a `BOOLEAN` data type (PL/SQL does but SQL does not until version 23c).

If you want to evaluate an expression then use a `CASE` expression to evaluate the expression and map it to scalar values such as `True`/`False`, `Y`/`N` or `1`/`0`:

```sql
with tbl (id, number_as_str) as (
  select 1, '3'  from dual
  union all select 2,'2' from dual
)
select id,
       number_as_str,
       CASE WHEN id=number_as_str THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS is_equal
from   tbl;
```

Which outputs:

| ID | NUMBER_AS_STR | IS_EQUAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | false |
| 2 | 2 | true |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tFwSrVnj)

Comment: @MTO -- thanks for the answer an explanation. Sorry for the stupid question, but when do you use Oracle SQL vs PL/SQL?

Comment: @David542 PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language (similar to T-SQL in SQL Server). It is used in functions, procedures, etc. and in anonymous PL/SQL blocks.

Comment: @David542 An example of SQL compared to PL/SQL is [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P9mnEqWG)

Comment: Wow, that gets really complex quickly. Almost like an entirely different language.